# Qual é a diferença entre "=" e ":=" no Make?

Tags: c, c++, build, makefile, make

No contexto de atribuíção de variáveis no **Make**, existem dois operadores que parecem fazer a mesma coisa: `=` e `:=`. Existe alguma diferença entre eles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existe uma diferença fundamental entre eles no que diz respeito à **consistência** do valor da variável de acordo com a posição no código em que ela é expandida.

Respectivamente, os operadores de atribuição `:=` e `=` funcionam da seguinte forma:

---

### Atribuição simples `:=`

Uma expressão de atribuição simples é avaliada (*evaluated*) somente uma vez, isto é, em sua primeira ocorrência no código. Por exemplo, se `CC := ${GCC} ${FLAGS}` tem seu valor expandido para `gcc -W` em sua primeira utilização, então toda vez que `${CC}` ocorrer será utilizado esse mesmo valor.

### Atribuição recursiva `=`

Uma expressão de atribuição recursiva é avaliada (*evaluated*) toda vez que a variável é encontrada no código. Por exemplo, uma declaração como `CC = ${GCC} ${FLAGS}` será avaliada somente quando uma ação como `${CC} file.c` é executada. Porém, se a variável `GCC` for reatribuída (p.ex. `GCC=c++`), a variável `${CC}` será convertida para `c++ -W` depois dessa reatribuição.

---

Essas informações e mais detalhes sobre sua implementação podem ser encontrados na documentação do GNU Make, na seção [6.2 The Two Flavors of Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) .

<sub>*Resposta adaptada da pergunta original do Stack Overflow [What's the difference between := and = in Makefile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879592/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-makefile)*</sub>